# Importing ZIPPED CSV files (depending on their NAME)

Tags: sas

I try to import a selection of ZIPPED CSV files into SAS BASE 9.4. This is working file by file, but I would like to import all CSV files named like "AXAMCE" followed by any other character.

I have working code for 1 file, but the ZIP contains also other file which I'd like to read beginning with the same characters "AXAMCE"

How to read all CSV files in the ZIP beginning with AXAMCE.D1905 into 1 SAS file?

infile ziplib("AXAMCE.D190524.T0210.CSV")  firstobs =2 ;

Comment: FILENAME ziplib zip "c:\data\2019-05C.zip";
data test;
   infile ziplib("AXAMCE.D190524.T0210.CSV")  firstobs =2 ;
   input var $20.;
run;

Comment: Do they all have the exact same structure?  Did you try using wildcard in the INFILE statement?  Try `ziplib("AXAMCE.D1905*") `

Comment: Great, this wildcard is working! Thank you, Tom!